# Send HTML emails with inline images with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple ActionMailer class like this:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def mail(from, to, cc, bcc, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)
    @subject = subject
    @recipients = to
    @from = from
    @cc = cc
    @bcc = bcc
    @sent_on = sent_at
    @body["message"] = message
    @headers = {}
  end
end
```

And I ue it like this from a controller:

```
MyMailer.deliver_mail(mail.from, mail.to, mail.cc, mail.bcc, mail.subject, mail.message)
```

I prefer to keep it simple with no templates or such, and it is a webservice with no views.

How do I change it to be able to send HTML mails with embedded images (in img tags i mean)? I need to attach the images woth the correct mime-type and also set the body with the correct mime-type, but how?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you seen:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments
for rails3

and:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments

for rails2

Answer (score 5):

If you are using rails3, it is dead easy, as explained in section 2.3.3 "Making Inline Attachments" [in this ruby on rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)